# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: spring, hibernate

When I trying to log in I have this problem:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order orders0_ where orders0_.user_id=10' at line 1
ERROR: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order orders0_ where orders0_.user_id=10' at line 1
```

here is entities User and Orders:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;
    private String sex;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private String login;

    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(0);
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>(0);

    public User(){}

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(Set<Order> orders) {
        if(orders!=null){
            this.orders = orders;
        }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {

    private int id;
    private OrderStatus status;
    private DeliveryType deliveryType;
    private Date date;
    private PaymentType paymentType;
    private String receiver;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private BigDecimal deliveryPrice;
    private String address;
    private String cardNumber;
    private String cardTermOf;
    private int cardThreeNumbers;

    public Order(){}

    private User user;  

    private Set<ProductsInOrder> productsInOrders = new HashSet<ProductsInOrder>();

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

When I change `FetchType.EAGER` on `FetchType.LAZY` in User Entity on method getOrderds() I can succesfuly log in, but when I trying to get my orders I obtain an error:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: "ua.sombra.webstore.domain.User.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session"

I can not solve this problem. What i need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `order` is reserved word in SQL and you cannot use it as a name for your table. Rename it to `orders` or smth..

Comment: In my case I renamed my table name from 'order' to 'orders' because order is the reserved keyword of MySQL. Don't change in your code only change your table name from 'user' to 'users' in the MySQL and in the annotation @Table(name="users")